# Force.com Apex code counter part or equivalent code to Java

Tags: java, salesforce, apex-code, apex, force.com

I am not certain if I am on the right path. Since I am not getting any data with the HTTP Request. I needed to convert this java code into force.com apex for me to be able to use a WTS web service.

```
public static HttpEntity getRequestEntity()
{
  JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
  HttpEntity entity = null;
  JSONObject jsonElement = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject();
  jsonElement.put("tenant",jsonObj);
  jsonObj.put("companyKey",companyName);

  String json = jsonElement.toJSONString();
  try {
    entity = new StringEntity(json);
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return entity;
}

private static void GetEnabledUsers(String responseContent) throws ParseException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
String url  = "<endpoint>/services/UserService1.svc/GetEnabledUsers";

// Create an http client to perform the http communication
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

// Http request to specific web service. Request will be given to client
HttpPost request =  new HttpPost(url);

// Create credentials for the authentication
CredentialsProvider provider =  new BasicCredentialsProvider();

UsernamePasswordCredentials credential = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(companyName+'\\'+userName, password);
provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credential);
HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
localContext.setCredentialsProvider(provider);

// Make the actual http request
HttpPost httpRequest =  new HttpPost(url);

HttpEntity requestEntity = getRequestEntity();
if(requestEntity != null) {
httpRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httpRequest.setEntity(requestEntity);
}

CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest, localContext);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseContent1 = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
System.out.println(responseContent1);
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
String userName= '<userName>';
String password= '<password>';
String companeyKey = '<companeyKey>';

JSONGenerator jsonGenerator = JSON.createGenerator(true);
jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
  jsonGenerator.writeFieldName('tenant');
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
      jsonGenerator.writeStringField('companeyKey', '<companeyKey>');
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();

requestBody = jsonGenerator.getAsString();

Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(userName + ':' + password);
HttpRequest requestEntity = new HttpRequest();
String authHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);

requestEntity.setMethod('POST');
requestEntity.setEndPoint('<endpoint>/services/UserService1.svc/GetEnabledUsers');
requestEntity.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
requestEntity.setHeader('Authorization', authHeader);
requestEntity.setBody(requestBody); 

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse responseEntity = http.send(requestEntity);

system.debug(responseEntity);
```

Comment: Seems like you're on the right track. What's in the debug log ?

Comment: @superfell I am getting Error 404

Comment: to be exact, System.HttpResponse[Status=Not Found, StatusCode=404]

Comment: do you have the right URL, is <endpoint> correctly resolved publicly

Comment: @superfell yep I am pretty much sure that the endpoint is correct as I am getting it from the Replicon Service GUI, I also tried this web service in their GUI and its returning some datas that I should get as well from my HTTP request. Btw I double check the endpoint and tried something and I am now getting "System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]"

Comment: 401 is unauthenticated, are you sure the service supports basic auth. You might want to dump all the response headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116638/discussion-between-jf-mechs-and-superfell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On difference seems to be around how the username is constructed for the auth parameter, change

`Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(userName + ':' + password);`

to

`Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(companyKey + '\\' + userName + ':' + password);`